# Expecting error handling while Jest Test on NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs, koa

I want to test my KoaJS controller. And my controller like that:

```
public static async myController (ctx: Context): Promise<void> {

        var body = {};
        var status = 406;

        const var1 = ctx.request.body.var1;
        
        if (var1 !== 0) {
 
            const error = new CustomException('title' ,'message' ,10)
            throw error
        }
           
            status = 200;
            body = var1;
        
        ctx.status = status;
        ctx.body = body;
}
```

And My test snipped like that:

```
    test('Getting error by wrong var1 value', async () => {
        const context = {status: undefined, body: undefined, request : {body: {"var1" : "123"}} } as Context;
        await CustomController.myController(context);
        expect(context).toThrow(CustomException)
        });

});
```

So When I run to test, I getting an error like that:

```
      53 |         if (var1 !== 0) {
      54 |             
    > 55 |             const error = new CustomException('title' ,'message' ,10)
         |                           ^
      56 |             throw error
      57 |         }

A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks.
```

Im new to Testing. I spend much time for this error. How can I solve this problem? Why Im getting this error?

Comment: what happens when you try the advice in that error message?

Comment: Now I getting an error on  :     app.listen(config.port, () => {
     
        console.log(`Server running on port ${config.port}`);});

Comment: Seems like a different issue to me. I think you should ask a different question.